# CoreAudio API in Borland Builder C++ 6

Tags: c++, core-audio, c++builder

I need to use CoreAudio API to control Volume in Windows 7 and with borland builder c++, it seems not possible. 
It seems like I can't use these Windows SDK header files for builder c++ because of version problems etc.

Comment: Sorry, but why on earth are you using C++ Builder 6? The community edition of Visual Studio 2012 is free and C++B6 is a very old IDE with a very old compiler.

Comment: In that case unless you can get hold of a version of the Windows SDK from around 2002 that you can work with I can see this being an exercise in futility.

Comment: Since older versions of Windows SDK have no CoreAudio API support, how do you think would it work?

Comment: It doesn't sound like this is possible then, older SDKs don't have the API you require and you can't use the newer SDKs with your ancient compiler. You need to talk to your manager about his expectations and your constraints for this project.

Comment: One solution in mind is to generate a simple win32 dll exporting the necessary functions in latest visual studio using this API and load and use that dll in my project. Other can be taking header files of this API from new SDK and using them in older SDK along with their dll's. The headers will bring all the dependencies as well removing extra deftypes and dependencies. Something like that. Have to discuss though.

Answer (score 1):

`__RPC__in` is defined in `rpcsal.h`, which is not included in C++Builder 6 (it was added in C++Builder 2007).  You can define `__RPC__in` (and other related defines) manually in your code as needed before then including `mmdeviceapi.h`, eg:

```
#ifndef __RPCSAL_H_VERSION__
#define __RPC_in
// other related defines, such as __RPC__out...
#endif

#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
```

`__RPC__in` and other related symbols are just preprocessor macros to help code self-document itself, they don't actually do anything for a C++ compiler (but do for Microsoft's PreFAST analysis tool).

Here is the content of `rpcsal.h` (with PREFAST defines removed, otherwise the content is too large for StackOverflow to accept):

```
#pragma option push -b -a8 -pc -A- /*P_O_Push*/
/****************************************************************\
*                                                                *
* rpcsal.h - markers for documenting the semantics of RPC APIs   *
*                                                                *
* Version 1.0                                                    *
*                                                                *
* Copyright (c) 2004 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. *
*                                                                *
\****************************************************************/

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Introduction
//
// rpcsal.h provides a set of annotations to describe how RPC functions use their
// parameters - the assumptions it makes about them, adn the guarantees it makes 
// upon finishing.  These annotations are similar to those found in specstrings.h,
// but are designed to be used by the MIDL compiler when it generates annotations
// enabled header files.
//
// IDL authors do not need to annotate their functions declarations.  The MIDL compiler
// will interpret the IDL directives and use one of the annotations contained 
// in this header.  This documentation is intended to help those trying to  understand 
// the MIDL-generated header files or those who maintain their own copies of these files.
//
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Differences between rpcsal.h and specstrings.h
// 
// There are a few important differences between the annotations found in rpcsal.h and
// those in specstrings.h:
// 
// 1. [in] parameters are not marked as read-only.  They may be used for scratch space 
// at the server and changes will not affect the client.
// 2. String versions of each macro alleviates the need for a special type definition
//
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Interpreting RPC Annotations
//
// These annotations are interpreted precisely in the same way as those in specstrings.h.  
// Please refer to that header for information related to general usage in annotations. 
//
// To construct an RPC annotation, concatenate the appropriate value from each category
// along with a leading __RPC_.  A typical annotation looks like "__RPC__in_string".
//
// |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
// | RPC Annotations                                                                  |
// |------------|------------|---------|--------|----------|----------|---------------|
// |   Level    |   Usage    |  Size   | Output | Optional |  String  |  Parameters   |
// |------------|------------|---------|--------|----------|----------|---------------|
// | <>         | <>         | <>      | <>     | <>       | <>       | <>            |
// | _deref     | _in        | _ecount | _full  | _opt     | _string  | (size)        |
// | _deref_opt | _out       | _bcount | _part  |          |          | (size,length) |
// |            | _inout     |         |        |          |          |               |
// |            |            |         |        |          |          |               |
// |------------|------------|---------|--------|----------|----------|---------------|
//
// Level: Describes the buffer pointer's level of indirection from the parameter or
//          return value 'p'.
//
// <>         : p is the buffer pointer.
// _deref     : *p is the buffer pointer. p must not be NULL.
// _deref_opt : *p may be the buffer pointer. p may be NULL, in which case the rest of
//                the annotation is ignored.
//
// Usage: Describes how the function uses the buffer.
//
// <>     : The buffer is not accessed. If used on the return value or with _deref, the
//            function will provide the buffer, and it will be uninitialized at exit.
//            Otherwise, the caller must provide the buffer. This should only be used
//            for alloc and free functions.
// _in    : The function will only read from the buffer. The caller must provide the
//            buffer and initialize it. Cannot be used with _deref.
// _out   : The function will only write to the buffer. If used on the return value or
//            with _deref, the function will provide the buffer and initialize it.
//            Otherwise, the caller must provide the buffer, and the function will
//            initialize it.
// _inout : The function may freely read from and write to the buffer. The caller must
//            provide the buffer and initialize it. If used with _deref, the buffer may
//            be reallocated by the function.
//
// Size: Describes the total size of the buffer. This may be less than the space actually
//         allocated for the buffer, in which case it describes the accessible amount.
//
// <>      : No buffer size is given. If the type specifies the buffer size (such as
//             with LPSTR and LPWSTR), that amount is used. Otherwise, the buffer is one
//             element long. Must be used with _in, _out, or _inout.
// _ecount : The buffer size is an explicit element count.
// _bcount : The buffer size is an explicit byte count.
//
// Output: Describes how much of the buffer will be initialized by the function. For
//           _inout buffers, this also describes how much is initialized at entry. Omit this
//           category for _in buffers; they must be fully initialized by the caller.
//
// <>    : The type specifies how much is initialized. For instance, a function initializing
//           an LPWSTR must NULL-terminate the string.
// _full : The function initializes the entire buffer.
// _part : The function initializes part of the buffer, and explicitly indicates how much.
//
// Optional: Describes if the buffer itself is optional.
//
// <>   : The pointer to the buffer must not be NULL.
// _opt : The pointer to the buffer might be NULL. It will be checked before being dereferenced.
//
// String: Describes if the buffer is NULL terminated
//
// <>      : The buffer is not assumed to be NULL terminated
// _string : The buffer is assumed to be NULL terminated once it has been initialized
//
// Parameters: Gives explicit counts for the size and length of the buffer.
//
// <>            : There is no explicit count. Use when neither _ecount nor _bcount is used.
// (size)        : Only the buffer's total size is given. Use with _ecount or _bcount but not _part.
// (size,length) : The buffer's total size and initialized length are given. Use with _ecount_part
//                   and _bcount_part.
//
// Notes:
//
// 1. Specifying two buffer annotations on a single parameter results in unspecified behavior
//    (e.g. __RPC__in_bcount(5) __RPC__out_bcount(6)
// 
// 2. The size of the buffer and the amount that has been initialized are separate concepts.  
//    Specify the size using _ecount or _bcount.  Specify the amount that is initialized using 
//    _full, _part, or _string.  As a special case, a single element buffer does not need 
//    _ecount, _bcount, _full, or _part
// 
// 3. The count may be less than the total size of the buffer in which case it describes the 
//    accessible portion. 
// 
// 4. "__RPC__opt" and "__RPC_deref" are not valid annotations.
// 
// 5. The placement of _opt when using _deref is important:
//      __RPC__deref_opt_...      : Input may be NULL
//      __RPC__deref_..._opt      : Output may be NULL
//      __RPC__deref_opt_..._opt  : Both input and output may be NULL
//

#pragma once

#include <specstrings.h>

#ifndef __RPCSAL_H_VERSION__
#define __RPCSAL_H_VERSION__        ( 100 )
#endif // __RPCSAL_H_VERSION__

#ifdef __REQUIRED_RPCSAL_H_VERSION__
    #if ( __RPCSAL_H_VERSION__ < __REQUIRED_RPCSAL_H_VERSION__ )
        #error incorrect <rpcsal.h> version. Use the header that matches with the MIDL compiler.
    #endif
#endif


#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif  // #ifdef __cplusplus

#if (_MSC_VER >= 1000) && !defined(__midl) && defined(_PREFAST_)

// PREFAST defines removed for brevity...

#else   // not prefast

#define __RPC__range(min,max)
#define __RPC__in_range(min,max)

#define __RPC__in           
#define __RPC__in_string
#define __RPC__in_opt_string
#define __RPC__in_ecount(size) 
#define __RPC__in_ecount_full(size)
#define __RPC__in_ecount_full_string(size)
#define __RPC__in_ecount_part(size, length)
#define __RPC__in_ecount_full_opt(size)
#define __RPC__in_ecount_full_opt_string(size)
#define __RPC__inout_ecount_full_opt_string(size)
#define __RPC__in_ecount_part_opt(size, length)
#define __RPC__in_xcount(size) 
#define __RPC__in_xcount_full(size)
#define __RPC__in_xcount_full_string(size)
#define __RPC__in_xcount_part(size, length)
#define __RPC__in_xcount_full_opt(size)
#define __RPC__in_xcount_full_opt_string(size)
#define __RPC__inout_xcount_full_opt_string(size)
#define __RPC__in_xcount_part_opt(size, length)

#define __RPC__deref_in 
#define __RPC__deref_in_string
#define __RPC__deref_in_opt
#define __RPC__deref_in_opt_string
#define __RPC__deref_opt_in
#define __RPC__deref_opt_in_string
#define __RPC__deref_opt_in_opt
#define __RPC__deref_opt_in_opt_string
#define __RPC__deref_in_ecount(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_in_ecount_part(size, length) 
#define __RPC__deref_in_ecount_full(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_in_ecount_full_opt(size)
#define __RPC__deref_in_ecount_full_string(size)
#define __RPC__deref_in_ecount_full_opt_string(size)
#define __RPC__deref_in_ecount_opt(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_in_ecount_opt_string(size)
#define __RPC__deref_in_ecount_part_opt(size, length) 
#define __RPC__deref_in_xcount(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_in_xcount_part(size, length) 
#define __RPC__deref_in_xcount_full(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_in_xcount_full_opt(size)
#define __RPC__deref_in_xcount_full_string(size)
#define __RPC__deref_in_xcount_full_opt_string(size)
#define __RPC__deref_in_xcount_opt(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_in_xcount_opt_string(size)
#define __RPC__deref_in_xcount_part_opt(size, length) 

// [out]
#define __RPC__out     
#define __RPC__out_ecount(size) 
#define __RPC__out_ecount_part(size, length) 
#define __RPC__out_ecount_full(size)
#define __RPC__out_ecount_full_string(size)
#define __RPC__out_xcount(size) 
#define __RPC__out_xcount_part(size, length) 
#define __RPC__out_xcount_full(size)
#define __RPC__out_xcount_full_string(size)

// [in,out] 
#define __RPC__inout                                   
#define __RPC__inout_string
#define __RPC__opt_inout
#define __RPC__inout_ecount(size)                     
#define __RPC__inout_ecount_part(size, length)    
#define __RPC__inout_ecount_full(size)          
#define __RPC__inout_ecount_full_string(size)          
#define __RPC__inout_xcount(size)                     
#define __RPC__inout_xcount_part(size, length)    
#define __RPC__inout_xcount_full(size)          
#define __RPC__inout_xcount_full_string(size)          

// [in,unique] 
#define __RPC__in_opt       
#define __RPC__in_ecount_opt(size)   
#define __RPC__in_xcount_opt(size)   


// [in,out,unique] 
#define __RPC__inout_opt    
#define __RPC__inout_opt_string    
#define __RPC__inout_ecount_opt(size)  
#define __RPC__inout_ecount_part_opt(size, length) 
#define __RPC__inout_ecount_full_opt(size)     
#define __RPC__inout_ecount_full_string(size)
#define __RPC__inout_xcount_opt(size)  
#define __RPC__inout_xcount_part_opt(size, length) 
#define __RPC__inout_xcount_full_opt(size)     
#define __RPC__inout_xcount_full_string(size)

// [out] **
#define __RPC__deref_out   
#define __RPC__deref_out_string
#define __RPC__deref_out_opt 
#define __RPC__deref_out_opt_string
#define __RPC__deref_out_ecount(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_out_ecount_part(size, length) 
#define __RPC__deref_out_ecount_full(size)  
#define __RPC__deref_out_ecount_full_string(size)
#define __RPC__deref_out_xcount(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_out_xcount_part(size, length) 
#define __RPC__deref_out_xcount_full(size)  
#define __RPC__deref_out_xcount_full_string(size)


// [in,out] **, second pointer decoration. 
#define __RPC__deref_inout    
#define __RPC__deref_inout_string
#define __RPC__deref_inout_opt 
#define __RPC__deref_inout_opt_string
#define __RPC__deref_inout_ecount_full(size)
#define __RPC__deref_inout_ecount_full_string(size)
#define __RPC__deref_inout_ecount_opt(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_inout_ecount_part_opt(size, length) 
#define __RPC__deref_inout_ecount_full_opt(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_inout_ecount_full_opt_string(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_inout_xcount_full(size)
#define __RPC__deref_inout_xcount_full_string(size)
#define __RPC__deref_inout_xcount_opt(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_inout_xcount_part_opt(size, length) 
#define __RPC__deref_inout_xcount_full_opt(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_inout_xcount_full_opt_string(size) 

// #define __RPC_out_opt    out_opt is not allowed in rpc

// [in,out,unique] 
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout  
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_string
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_ecount(size)     
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_ecount_part(size, length) 
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_ecount_full(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_ecount_full_string(size)
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_xcount(size)     
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_xcount_part(size, length) 
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_xcount_full(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_xcount_full_string(size)

#define __RPC__deref_out_ecount_opt(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_out_ecount_part_opt(size, length) 
#define __RPC__deref_out_ecount_full_opt(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_out_ecount_full_opt_string(size)
#define __RPC__deref_out_xcount_opt(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_out_xcount_part_opt(size, length) 
#define __RPC__deref_out_xcount_full_opt(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_out_xcount_full_opt_string(size)

#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_opt      
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_opt_string
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_ecount_opt(size)   
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_ecount_part_opt(size, length) 
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_ecount_full_opt(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_ecount_full_opt_string(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_xcount_opt(size)   
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_xcount_part_opt(size, length) 
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_xcount_full_opt(size) 
#define __RPC__deref_opt_inout_xcount_full_opt_string(size) 

#define __RPC_full_pointer  
#define __RPC_unique_pointer
#define __RPC_ref_pointer
#define __RPC_string                               


#endif

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif


#pragma option pop /*P_O_Pop*/
```

Then you can do:

```
#include "rpcsal.h"
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I couldn't try it though as we came up with a solution of generating the code for borland of mmdeviceapi.idl to type lib and then using the utility tlibimp.exe and then keeping only the functions which we needed. Later on we also had to take the code for IAudioEndpointVolume interface and a few more to prepare a compact header file. and for using that classes and interfaces, we wrote a small wrapper class. now all works fine :)